# How to play audio on non-activated tab with chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing chrome extension, I made a button on an active tab(AT), if you press it, it sends message to content script on a specific non-active tab(NAT) and emulates there "click" event to play some audio content (which it gets by http request). But I have a problem - after I press button on AT, nothing is played. Then I activate NAT - and audio plays, so playing is defered. After that I go back to AT and press the button again - and audio plays without breaks.
The question - Is there any methods to force playing audio on non-active tabs? 
Or maybe short-time activation of specific tab would be the best way?

Comment: only way is to activate the inactive tab. research the tabs api, then show us attempts and issues.

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll try it.